# How to pass the hidden input value to another script PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a file called **form.php** where the form is and one of inputs is

```
<input type="hidden" name="relate" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
```

How can i get the value of this input to another page called
**details.php**.
Im trying to pass it like

```
$form=$_POST['relate'];
```

but it doesnt work!!!

Any idea ?

Comment: add form tag code...

Comment: post the function the_ID() as well...done

Comment: they already are, but i didnt mention all the code here!

Comment: @flow we are asking to add the code here.

Comment: Hello @flow, could you update you code to reflect the issue you have ? You're missing a lot of info there.

Comment: <form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="relate" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
</form>

the other page contains a lot of code but what i need is just to pass the value of that hidden input than from that im going to make a database select where the value of this input is the CONDITION in the database SELECT!

Answer (score 1):

You must make a form with `action="details.php"`

```
<form action="details.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="relate" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
    ... other input fields and submit button
</form>
```

And then on details.php after you check if is form submitted and values are set, you can get value

```
$relate_value = $_POST['relate'];
```

Edit:

Let me try to solve your problem here. This should be page where is your form (form.php)

```
//extract hiddoen value from the post
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://your_domain.com/details.php';// or another location where is details.php script with this query
$fields = array(
    'relate' => urlencode($_POST['relate']),        
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

After this your on your script details.php query should be executed

Comment: i need to get the value of that hidden input to use it on another page where the value of that hidden input will be used as condition in SELECT STATEMENT!
the form is already made and ready to use but i didnt post all the code here!

Comment: So basicly what are you saying is that you have a form that already works but you need this one hidden field to send to another page just to put it  in query?

Comment: yeahhh exactly that, atleast someone have cleared what im needing

Comment: Did you try to use, for example, `curl` to post this value to that another page?

Comment: im stucked at URI, my details.php page is actually a wordpress admin page created through functions @Standej